# Which method is the right way to setup multiple trackers in Google (Universal) Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm setting up multiple trackers to track 2 properties I setup in my Google Analytics.  I found this link from Google which I use to set this up as the following:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-6', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-8', 'auto', 'clientTracker');
ga('clientTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

However, when I search online I see people responding with the following:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-6', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-8', 'auto', {'name': 'clientTracker'});
ga('clientTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Should I be using just **'clientTracker'** or **{'name': 'clientTracker'}** in my Universal tracking code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid and do the same thing. The documentation indicates the `ga()` function's signature is:

```
ga(command, [...fields], [fieldsObject])
```

and https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#method-details indicates the `create` operation's `fields` are:

```
ga('create', [trackingId], [cookieDomain], [name], [fieldsObject]);
```

The docs also note that:

> If a field is set in both a `fields` parameter and `fieldsObject`, the value in `fieldsObject` will be used.

so either way is valid, and the second way will override the first.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code because it's descriptive:-
     {'name': 'clientTracker'}

Comment: That's more personal preference than a useful answer, IMO.