# Google analytic multi tracker will result in http no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

```
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


            ga('create', 'UA-demo-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

            ga('create', 'UA-demo-2', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The code is to implemented GA. I have put that into header. the problem is , the later tracker will return http no response if there is multi tracker. it works fine for single tracker, though.

How to fix that? Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: I suggest you try named trackers (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761700/which-method-is-the-right-way-to-setup-multiple-trackers-in-google-universal-a), since creating two trackers with the same name will result in one overwriting the other (not sure this will help with the specific problem, though, but since you should do it in any case to avoid problems further down the road it's worth a try).

Comment: yes, named the second tracker fixed the problem, thanks a lot